# SyntaxError on identitcal pages

Tags: url, segments

I have two pages serving up the exact same static page. I get an error on the second page, but I can’t figure out why.

**No error:** jatecson.com/information

**Error:** jatecson.com/set/images

I get this error in Chrome:
“Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <”

In Safari I get another error:
Did not parse stylesheet at ‘jatecson.com/set/css/main.css’ because non CSS MIME types are not allowed in strict mode.

Clicking on the error in the console takes me to line 1 of the web page:

Can anyone offer a suggestion on how to fix this?

I’m running EE 2.10.1.

Answer (score 1):

... My friend, did you check your resources? You are getting an error on the second page because you are accessing your `Main.js` from **relative paths** in your template.

**jatecson.com/information** : http://jatecson.com/js/Main.js

Load that file and *yay*! We've loaded your JavaScript file.

**jatecson.com/set/images** : http://jatecson.com/set/js/Main.js

Load that file ... and... hrmmm. That doesn't seem right...

You must be loading resources with a relative path in that template, when you should be using the `{site_url}` variable to direct your resources to absolute paths.

Here is your code to load that JavaScript file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Main.js"></script>
```

You are loading from a relative path! So when your URI is `/` (base site root), you get `http://jatecson.com/js/Main.js`. But when your URI is `/set/`, you're getting `http://jatecson.com/set/js/Main.js`. This is true of all of your resource tags. If these are ExpressionEngine parsed templates, you should use the `{site_url}` path like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{site_url}js/Main.js"></script>
```

You might need to add a `/` after `{site_url}`, depending on what it's set at.

If these aren't ExpressionEngine templates and actual flat static served files, you'll need to edit them and manually add your domain to those `src` parameters.

Comment: This would be my guess too.  You are getting a parse failure for main.css because it contains a '<'.  If gets a '<' in it because it if not returning a CSS file, but an HTML formatted error page.